# unflatten/reshape json_normalize into dataframe and export as excel file

Tags: json, excel, reshape

I am trying to extract 'date_value','country_code','confirmed' to form 1 excel file output then extract 'date_value', 'country_code','deaths' to form another excel file output from this nested JSON structure below. [Attached actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3QPc.png) is a cut down version of the JSON code which contains at least 200 countries and each country has it's own measurement.

I used json_normalize on output['data'] in order to extract the values I need. After that I managed to get the desired output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lClgf.png), however what I want is [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpCCz.png). I have tried melt, wide_to_long, pivot_table, unstack, etc but they all give me similar error: 'Data must be 1-dimensional'. How can I transform my data to the desired output so I can export it as excel file looking like [this final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWviN.png) output?

Here's the structure of the JSON code:

```
Output['Data']: { scale: Object //Scale for visualisations
    { deaths: Object, //Min and max int values in returned data
      confirmed: Object, //Min and max int values in returned data
      stringency: Object, //Min and max int values in returned data
},
    countries: [Array of Strings //3 letter country codes in returned data],
         data: {YYYY-MM-DD: { //Key is date in YYYY-MM-DD format
          BRA: { //3 letter country code
                date_value: YYYY-MM-DD, //Repeat of date in key
              country_code: BRA, //Repeat of country code in key
                 confirmed: Integer, //Value of confirmed cases
                    deaths: Integer, //Value of deaths
         stringency_actual: Integer, //Calculated value for day. Can be null if no value available
                stringency: Integer, //Display value for day **1.
                   }
                   }
                   }
```

Comment: Please do not put code into images, or even worse: image links. Put them on code blocks, otherwise people won't even start reading it.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Thanks for the tips, new to this but I have now amended it